# How to show the contact page in Joomla?

Tags: contacts, joomla2.5

I made a contact person in Joomla 2.5.1 and a contact link.

On the front end it shows the contact informations and the contact form in an accordion.

How can I get rid off it and show the whole contact page?

**EDIT**

Altough its the default Joomla behaviour i link a screenshot to make easier to understand what im talking about: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/687/contactis.jpg

Here u can see the contact form opened, and the other contact panels closed.

Comment: can you provide more details? (even a screenshot or two) or maybe a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the right hand side under "Contact Display Option" set "Display format" to Plain:

http://prntscr.com/713e2

Answer (score 1):

Just fill an email address to the contact details so as to make the contact form to send to, else the form will have no recipient email so, no form will be displayed. Also set display to "Plain"